# How to generate ANFIS output in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I am using ANFIS for my work and learned use [ANFIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fp715dup12.html) using MATLAB. However, I am getting my final FIS output in chart. I am not able to get output in array form.

Would you please help me on how to get the final output in array form?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fp715dup12.html#FP43334 :

```
The command anfis takes at least two and at most six input arguments. The general format is

[fismat1,trnError,ss,fismat2,chkError] = ...
anfis(trnData,fismat,trnOpt,dispOpt,chkData,method);

where trnOpt (training options), dispOpt (display options), chkData (checking data), and method (training method), are optional.
```

Then you can for example plot the output:

```
figure(3)
subplot(2,2,1)
plotmf(fismat2, 'input', 1)
subplot(2,2,2)
plotmf(fismat2, 'input', 2)
subplot(2,2,3)
plotmf(fismat2, 'input', 3)
subplot(2,2,4)
plotmf(fismat2, 'input', 4)
```

The following plots show an example of the result:

[image]